# Python floats vs strings

Tags: python, string

I'm trying to code a cryptocurrency trading profit calculator that asks the user for input regarding the name of the crypto they bought, the price they bought it at, and the quantity of that crypto they bought. The program then calculates the price they would need to sell at in order to make a profit at various different percentages. When I run this code I get this error message:

> ```
> line 16, in <module>
>     print("sale Price: " + salePrice)
> TypeError: must be str, not float
> ```

Here is my code:

```
fee = 1.002

cryptoName = input("Crypto Name: ")
boughtPrice = float(input("Price When Bought: "))
numBought = float(input("Number bought: "))

feePrice = boughtPrice * fee

print(" ")
print(" ")

print("**********************")
print(".3% Profit: ")
salePrice = feePrice *1.003
print("**********************")
print("sale Price: " + salePrice)
print("----------------------")
newBalance = salePrice * numBought
invested = numBought * feePrice
totalProfit = newBalance - invested
print("Total Profit: " + totalProfit)
```

I'm more used to Java and I made this program originally in Java and I know in Java you can perform math on strings as long as some numerical value is associated with them but as I've found out, Python is different. How should I code this differently?

Comment: You must convert a float to a string before concatenation.

Answer (score 2):

You have some options. The first is just to convert to string and concatenate:

```
print("sale Price: " + str(salePrice))
```

But arguably better would be to use `.format()`:

```
print("sale Price: {}".format(salePrice))
```

Or, if using python 3.6 or above, use an `f-string`:

```
print(f"sale Price: {salePrice}")
```

Comment: I used print("sale Price: {}".format(salePrice)) and that works the way I wanted it to. TY!